# How to create a simple REST api WEB application with Python

Tags: python, api, rest

We can make REST api application with spring boot by start.spring.io web site easily, anyone know any good website through which I can get the skeleton REST api project with python? My intention is to make REST api application with python.

Comment: Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways to do this is by using the requests module in Python. Import it into your code with the following command:

import requests

Now, each API is different, so you'll have to see with the vendor what the requirements are. For testing and learning purposes, I recommend using httpbin (https://httpbin.org). You can test pretty much anything there.

Here are a few simple requests:

```
#returning status
url = 'https://httpbin.org/post'
response = requests.post(url)
print(response.status_code)
print(response.ok)


#sending data/getting text response
url = 'https://httpbin.org/post'
params = {'Jello':'World'}
response = requests.post(url, params=params)
print(response.text)


#sending data/getting json response
url = 'https://httpbin.org/post'
params = {'Jello':'World'}
response = requests.post(url, params=params)
print(response.json())


#sending time data to server
import datetime
url = 'https://httpbin.org/post'
params = {'Time':f'{datetime.datetime.now()}'}
response = requests.post(url, params=params)
print(response.text)


#Params vs Data
#params
url = 'https://httpbin.org/post'
params = {'username':'jsmith','password':'abc123'}
response = requests.post(url, params=params)
print(response.text)

#data
url = 'https://httpbin.org/post'
payload = {'username':'jsmith','password':'abc123'}
response = requests.post(url, data=payload)
print(response.text)


# ********* HEADERS **********
url = 'https://httpbin.org/get'
response = requests.get(url)
print(response.text)

url = 'https://httpbin.org/post'
headers = {'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'}
response = requests.post(url,headers=headers)
print(response.request.headers) #client request headers
print(response.headers) #server response headers
print(response.headers['content-type']) #request header value from server
```

To use actual APIs, I suggest RapidAPI (https://rapidapi.com/), which is a hub where you can connect to thousands of APIs. HEre is a sample code using Google translate:

```
#RapidAPI
#Google Translate
import requests
url = "https://google-translate1.p.rapidapi.com/language/translate/v2"

text = 'Ciao mondo!'
to_lang = 'en'
from_lang = 'it'

payload = f"q={text}&target={to_lang}&source={from_lang}"
headers = {
    'content-type': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    'accept-encoding': "application/gzip",
    'x-rapidapi-host': "google-translate1.p.rapidapi.com",
    'x-rapidapi-key': "your-API-key"
    }

response = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers)

print(response.json()['data']['translations'][0]['translatedText'])
```